# Strange syntax error in with..do..else statement

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a syntax error that I don't know where it comes from. Here is my function (in persona_from_auth.ex):

```
  # find or create the user.
  # if you login with oauth2, your account will auto created
  def find_or_create(%Auth{provider: :github} = auth) do
    with
      {:notfound} <- check_github_email(auth.info.email),
      {:notfound} <- check_google_email(auth.info.email)
    do
        create(auth)
    else
      {:ok, persona} -> update(auth, persona)
    end
  end
```

This returns the following error:

```
== Compilation error on file web/models/persona_from_auth.ex ==
** (SyntaxError) web/models/persona_from_auth.ex:18: syntax error before: do
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

Line 18 is the line before the create() call.

I checked for the correct elixir version. Turned out in mix.exs I had 1.2, I changed that to 1.4.2 but still the same error. Is it possible that compilation still uses 1.2? How do I check that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first statement after `with` must either be on the same line or the arguments need to be in parentheses, or else Elixir thinks you're trying to call `with/0` and then the following lines don't make sense, resulting in the syntax error.

Either of the following should work:

```
with {:notfound} <- check_github_email(auth.info.email),
     {:notfound} <- check_google_email(auth.info.email)
do
```

```
with(
  {:notfound} <- check_github_email(auth.info.email),
  {:notfound} <- check_google_email(auth.info.email)
) do
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there some principal difference between `with` and `do` and `else` ? The latter can be on a line by themselves.

Comment: Yes, `do` and `else` are language keywords while `with` is not. You cannot create a function or variable with the name `do` or `else`. You can try `do = 1`, `else = 1`, and `with = 1` in `iex`. Only `with` will work.

Comment: Looks like there's an unmatched bracket in the first code block of this answer. The last bracket shouldn't be there, no?